# Задача о копилке с монетами

Tags: pascal

Вот задача. В принципе идеи были ее решения: это динамика или рекурсия. Но безрезультатно. Прошу помочь в составление алгоритма, т.к. рекурсию я просто терпеть не могу и редко ее понимаю, поэтому просто нужно составить ход решения задачи, понятный и ясный, чтоб большого труда в переводе на Pascal не составило.

П.С. можно написать и саму программу, с пояснениями...

[image: текст задачи]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [**задача о рюкзаке**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5) с некоторыми дополнительными условиями. Во-первых, нам необходимо собрать рюкзак размера **ровно** `(F-E)`, а во вторых необходимо решить эту же задачу, но не максимизируя конечный вес, а минимизируя его.

---

*Для конкретно вашего случая известно решение с помощью динамического программирования, которое работает за псевдополиномиальное время.*

Вам остается только слегка модифицировать саму динамику для того, чтобы искалось решение с весом **точно равным** `(F-E)`, а не **меньше либо равные ему** и запустить его 2 раза - на максимизацию и на минимизацию.

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная задача на ДП.
Вот ход решения:

- пусть f[i] - максимальная сумма, которую мы можем набрать некоторыми монетами, так что их суммарный вес равен i.
- Очевидно, что f[0] = 0.
- Заполним значения всех ячеек массива f минус бесконечностью (-maxlongint).
- Будем пробегаться по индексам массива f начиная с 0. Пусть текущий индекс в массиве f равен i. Если f[i] != maxlongint (!= это не равно), значит мы как-то смогли набрать вес i. Тогда перебираем все монеты (по индексу j) и пробуем "пихнуть" её в наше ДП. Т.е. если f[i+w[j]] < f[i] + p[j] (если мы добавим нашу монету (суммарный вес тогда равен i+w[j]), то если сумма, которую набрали до этого (равная f[i+w[j]]), меньше чем та, которую мы можем получить добавлением к текущей сумме новой монеты (f[i] + p[j])), то обновляем наш ответ для этого веса: f[i+w[j]] = f[i] + p[j];

Теперь, если в f[WITH_W - WITHOUT_W] == -maxlongint, то мы не смогли набрать нужную сумму, поэтому This is impossible. (WITH_W , WITHOUT_W - вес копилки **С** монетами и **без** монет)

Аналогично для поиска минимальной суммы.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример решения, на JavaScript. Можно проверить в браузере

> ```
> function calc( sum, cost, weight ){
>   var min = [],             //Массив минимальных стоимостей
>       max = [],             //Массив максимальных стоимостей
>       c_cost, c_weight,     //Вес/Стоимость текущей монет
>       c_min, c_max,         //Мин/Макс стоимости для данного веса
>       t_min, t_max,         //Мин/Макс вес который получиться при
>                             //добавлении этой монеты
>       w, j,                 //Счётчик по весу и по монетам
>       mj = cost.length;     //Ограничение на кол-во монет
>
>   min[0] = max[0] = 0;      //Для веса 0 и 0
>
>   //Проходим по всем весам
>   for ( w = 1; w <= sum; w++ ){
>     c_min = 0;              //Изначально, такого веса нельзя получить
>     c_max = 0;              //и потому его мин и макс стоимости - 0
>
>     //Проходим по библиотеке монет
>     for ( j = 0; j < mj; j++ ){
>       c_cost = cost[j];       //Сохраняем данные
>       c_weight = weight[j];   //Текущей монеты
>
>       //Если вес текущей монеты равен текущему весу,
>       //то этот вес можно получить
>       if ( w == c_weight ){
>         //Если вес не достигался ранее, или его мин стоимость больше моей
>         if ( ( c_min == 0 ) || ( c_min > c_cost ) ) c_min = c_cost;
>
>         //Если макс стоимость меньше моей
>         if ( c_max < c_cost ) c_max = c_cost;
>       }
>       //Если вес текущей монеты больше текущему весу
>       else if ( w > c_weight ){
>         //Вычисляем какими станут мин и макс стоимости
>         //при добавлении этой монеты
>         t_min = min[ w - c_weight ] + c_cost;
>         t_max = max[ w - c_weight ] + c_cost;
>
>         //Если вес ( w - c_weight ) - достигается,
>         //то если вес не достигался ранее, или его мин стоимость больше моей
>         if ( ( t_min != c_cost ) &&
>              ( ( c_min == 0 ) || ( c_min > t_min ) )
>           ) c_min = t_min;
>
>         //Если вес не достигался ранее, или его макс стоимость меньше моей
>         if ( ( t_max != c_cost ) && ( c_max < t_max ) ) c_max = t_max;
>       }
>     }
>
>     //Записываем данные в память
>     min[ w ] = c_min;
>     max[ w ] = c_max;
>   }
>
>   return [ min[sum], max[sum], min, max ];
> }
>
> cost = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
> weight = [ 2, 4, 5 ];
> sum = 36;
> res = calc( sum, cost, weight );
>
> if ( res[0] && res[1] ) console.log( res[0], ' ', res[1] );
> else console.log('This is impossible.');
> ```